# PyTorch Column-wise reduction using multiplication

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I'd like to reduce columns from a Torch tensor by multiplying all values from the same row.
So, for instance:

```
x = torch.tensor([[1,1,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,2], [1,2,2]])
```

Shape is 4*3. After the reduction, I'd like to have a tensor of shape 4 with each value being the product of each column ie.

```
x_reduced = torch.tensor([1,0,2,4])
```

Is there a torch operator to do that easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, the function call is simple: `torch.prod(x,dim = 1)`.